# All menu is locked when I go to the mix component menu in laravel mix

Tags: html, laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix

This is my Vuejs mix component side bar menu when I'm here then other all things locked

```
<li class=" {{ Request::is('products') ? 'active' : '' }}">
    <a href="{{ url('products') }}"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i> <span>Products</span></a>
</li>
<li class=" {{ Request::is('categories') ? 'active' : '' }}">
    <a href="{{ url('categories') }}"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i> <span>Categories</span></a>
</li>
```

think bootstrap assets not compiling when I hit the mix component. Please give me a solution how can compile assets and hit another menu attributes

this is my webpack.mix.js

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Comment: Post your mix file.

Comment: @bassxzero I did add the webpack.mix.js file above

Comment: Could you add your `resources/assets/js/app.js` too?

Comment: Make you are importing bootstrap `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';` in app.js

Comment: Make sure you are importing bootstrap in your app.scss file `@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';`

Comment: Did not work for me